# Excel - How to combine these formulas into one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this worksheet which lists results oldest to newest dates.

I have these three formulas..

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[HomeTeam],IF("H"=[FTR],IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],"")))),1),"NULL")

=IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[AwayTeam],IF("A"=[FTR],IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],"")))),1),"NULL")

=IF(AND([@[SLWD_H1]]="NULL",[@[SLWD_H2]]="NULL"),"NULL",MAX(Results[@[SLWD_H1]:[SLWD_H2]]))
```

Basically the first looks for the last time the home team won a game at home.

The second looks for the last time the home team won a game away from home.

And then the third gives me the latest date of the two mentioned above.

I was wondering if there was a way to combine all three into a single column instead of having to have three?

Thankyou in advance.

**EDIT

To make myself a bit clearer! What I want is to combine the above 3 into one formula which will output the result!

So it will find the date in example 1 and find the date in example 2 and then it will output the latest date.

Comment: Just concatenate the three formulas with your desired separator.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what I wanted!

I want to combined the three formulas to get the result! As in run 1 and 2 with 3 which will return the date!

Comment: If what you want for the result is the answer returned by formula 3,  then just use =max(formula1, formula2).  Or if the only possible entries in the HomeTeam column are "hometeam" or "awayteam", just eliminate that conditional test from the formula

Comment: I tried the Max(Formula1,Formula2) before posting and couldn't get it to work but have just figured out why! Because I was setting the value to NULL if the target was not hit and the of course NULL is larger than any date! Foolish me! Have sorted it now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **MAX** formula to determine the highest date between the home and away dates.

The formula would look like this:

=MAX(Number1,Number2)

The **MAX** formula will ignore the *NULL* text values.  However if both values are *NULL*, it will return a zero value.  If formatted as a date it will show as 00/01/1900

```
=MAX(IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[HomeTeam],IF("H"=[FTR],IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],"")))),1),"NULL"),IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[AwayTeam],IF("A"=[FTR],IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],"")))),1),"NULL"))
```

[image: Example of output of MAX formula]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, would an OR("A"=[FTR],"H"=[FTR]) work?  This would work like your first formula except using both "A" and "H" games.

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[AwayTeam],IF(OR("A"=[FTR],"H"=[FTR]),IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],"")))),1),"NULL")
```

Are these the only two values for [FTR]? If so you could just get rid of that IF statement entirely requiring either H or A:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF([@HomeTeam]=[AwayTeam],IF([Date]<[@Date],IF([@Season]=[Season],[Date],""))),1),"NULL")
```